# ASP.Net MVC Redirect to WWW domain version

Tags: asp.net-mvc-routing

For SEO purposes, I want to do a 301 redirect when anyone hits my domain name without the www. prefix. So, redirect from http://mydomain.com/{page} to http://www.mydomain.com/{page}.

Can I accomplish this with MVC routes? Or should I put some sort of global action filter on every controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No doubt you could, but the only reason to do so would be to demonstrate that you could.

In IIS, set up a website for the non www. domain.

Set it to do the redirect, not "to the exact URI" checked, because you want it to match "/{page}" to "/{page}", and also unless you plan to change this policy in the near future "permanent redirect" because unless you plan to change this policy in the near future, then for SEO purposes you do **not** want to 302, you want to 301.